# Не заполняется таблица на phpMyAdmin значениями,что пользователь ввел во время регистрации.Ошибок не выдает

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

```
<form action="vendor/signUp.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class ="modal3 modal-display-none">
    <div class="reg-modal-wind">
        <div class="modal-window-containing3">
            <div class="modal-header3">
                <h3 class="modal-header-title3">Регистрация</h3>
                <button class="escape3" type="button">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body3">
                <div class="input-reg">
                        <span class="plsINP span-input-login">Придумайте Логин:</span>
                        <input type="text" name="login" class="inp_aut imagine-log" placeholder="Логин">
                </div>
                <div class="input-reg-mail-reg">
                    <span class="plsINP span-input-login">Адрес электронной почты:</span>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="inp_aut mail-reg" placeholder="Электронная почта">
                </div>
                <div class="input-inmagine-pswd">
                    <span class="plsINP span-input-password">Придумайье пароль:</span>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="inp_aut pswd-reg" vlaue="" placeholder="Пароль">
                </div> 
                <div class="input-confirm-pswd">
                    <span class="plsINP span-input-password">Подтвердите пароль:</span>
                    <input type="password" name="password_confirm" class="inp_aut pswd-reg-conf" vlaue="" placeholder="Повторите Пароль">
                </div> 
                <div class="button_reg-block">
                 <button type="submit" class="button_reg">Регистрация</button>
                </div>
                <div class="if-log-block">
                    <span>Уже есть учетная запись,тогда войди!</span>
                    <a href="#" class="log-cho">Войти</a>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer3">
                <div class="modal-footer-links">
                <a href="#" class="modal-footer-link2"><img src="img/VK-modal.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#" class="modal-footer-link2"><img src="img/INST-modal.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#" class="modal-footer-link2"><img src="img/FACEBOOK-modal.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<?php
    //DB_connectioin
$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','interbud');
if ($connect){//header('Location:../index.php');
}
if (!$connect){
    die("Error with connecting DataBase");
}
?>
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'connect.php';

$login = $_POST['login'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password_confirm = $_POST['password_confirm'];

if($password === $password_confirm){
    $password=md5($password);

    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `login`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (NULL,'132', '$email', '$password')");
    $_SESSION['message']= "Регистрация прошла успешно!";
    header('Location:../index.php');

}else{
    $_SESSION['message']= "Пароли не совпадают";
    header('Location:../index.php');
}
```

Comment: вы в POST эти данные получаете?

Comment: да,проверял ранее